# Is python really slow or is it because I havent optimized the python code?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, performance

The Leetcode question is: Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

I coded in both C++ and Python to see whether there is a huge performance gap, and found the result to be:
[image: Performance Measure]

Here are the c++ and python implementations of the same logic:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int max_count=0;
        int k=1;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        bool visited[256];
        memset(visited,false,256);
        int n=s.size();
        
        while(k<=n && i<n && j<n){
            /*for(int l=i;l<=j;l++) cout << s[l];
            cout << endl;*/
            
            if(visited[int(s[j])]){
                memset(visited,false,256);
                k=1;
                i++;
                j=i+k-1;
            }else{
                if (max_count<k) max_count=k;
                visited[int(s[j])]=true;
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        return max_count;
    }
};
```

and

```py
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, a: str) -> int:
        
        #apply sliding window for k=0,1,2,..,n until repetition is found for a substring
        k=1 #wndow length
        i=0 #starting indx of substring
        j=0 #ending indx of substring
        init_visited=[False]*256
        visited=init_visited[:]
        max_count=0
        n=len(a)
        
        while k<=n and j<n and i<n:       
            #print(k,i,j)
            #print(a[i:j+1])
            if visited[ord(a[j])]:
                visited = init_visited[:]
                i+=1
                k=1
                j=i+k-1
            else:
                visited[ord(a[j])]=True
                max_count=max(max_count,k)
                
                k+=1
                j+=1
        
        return max_count
```

What could have I improved in the Python code to make it faster?

Comment: Cynical answers: Is python really slow? Yes. Is your code non-optimized? Yes.

Comment: Your question would probably attract much more insightful answers if it had been asked on codereview.stackexchange.com which is specifically about submitting a code that works and asking for any improvement

Comment: `memset(visited,false,256)` is most likely wrong; `sizeof(bool)` is usually not 1.

Comment: If you include the time it took to compile the C++ code, I bet you the Python version is faster ;-)

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n^2) because it looks at all substrings. It's possible to solve this in O(n), using a single pass over the input.

Comment: I recommend reading the doc for `std::vector`, which specifies that `std::vector<bool>` beneficiates from a different implementation than other vectors, and is particularly optimized for that purpose. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: @VerilogCoder - i'ved tried to optimize the Python and getting better performance. see below Post.

Comment: @interjay yeah in the mean time i implemented an O(n) solution using dictionaries and obtained the speed to be 8ms and 48ms for cpp and py code respectively.But my point is not optimizing the algorithm but optimizing the py code to match cpp speeds.

Comment: Apparently, a moderator declined to migrate this question to codereview.stackexchange.com, because they "didn't find enough evidence to support" that it should be migrated. Good luck, I hope you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python will never be as fast as C++ but you can optimize this function using a dictionary:

```
def longestsub(S):
    distinct = set()
    result   = 0
    start    = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(S):
        if c in distinct:
            result = max(result,i-start)
            distinct.difference_update(S[start:i])
            start  = i
        distinct.add(c)
    result = max(result,len(S)-start)
    return result
```

output:

```
testData = ["abcabcbb","bbbbb","pwwkew",""]
for s in testData:
    print(f"'{s}' : ",longestsub(s))

'abcabcbb' :  3
'bbbbb' :  1
'pwwkew' :  3
'' :  0
```

performance:

```
longestsub("abcabcbb"*10000) # 80,000 characters --> 3 in 30 ms
```